# Simulating PDOStatement::execute

Tags: php, caching, pdo, memcached

I am trying to extend my PDO class with functions from Memcache. In particular, I have created a function which I am calling `cache_execute` which allows me first check if the results exist in the cache, and then to return either the information from the cache, or the information from the database if the information does not yet exist in the cache (and to put the information IN the cache if it doesn't exist yet)

Here is an example of my current code:

```
namespace trf;
class StatementWithCaching extends \PDOStatement {
    public $db;
    public $cache;
    protected function __construct(&$db) {
        $this->db =& $db;
    }

    function cache_execute( $array = NULL , $cache = FALSE , $cacheTime = 1800 ) {
        if( is_a( $cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
            $query = $this->queryString;
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $query = str_replace(':' . $key , "'" . addslashes( $value ) . "'", $query );
            }
            try {
                $memResults = $this->mconn->get( md5( $this->queryString ) );
            }
            catch ( \Exception $e ) {
                $memResults = FALSE;
            }

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

My Question is - how do I place the information retrieved from the cache and store it where it can be retrieved by `PDOStatement::fetch()`, `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` etc.

My goal is to be able to run either `StatementWithCaching::execute()` or `StatementWithCaching::cache_execute()` and still retrieve the results the same way ( using `StatementWithCaching::fetch()` or `StatementWithCaching::fetchAll()` ).

Comment: you can't, not with pdostatement objects. they won't know anything about your cache. your main pdo wrapper should wrap "prepare"/"exec" and return your own objects which ARE cache-aware.

Comment: The problem isn't the cache, it's knowing how to store the information in a place that it can be retrieved by PDOStatement::fetch() or PDOStatement::fetchAll(), unless I mis-understood you.

Comment: and like I said, not possible with the pdostatement object. it knows NOTHING about your cache. so your pdo wrapper has to extend "prepare" to return a "MyCacheAwarePDOStatement" object instead, and that object extends pdostatement.

Comment: That's what StatementWithCaching is doing, but where do I store the results retrieved by the cache so that it can be retrieved by StatementWithCaching::fetch() or StatementWithCaching::fetchAll()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by extending the `PDOStatement::fetch()` and `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` functions.

```
namespace trf;
class StatementWithCaching extends \PDOStatement {
    protected $db;
    protected $cache;
    protected $cacheReturn;
    protected $cacheQuery;
    protected $queryCacheTime;
    protected function __construct(&$db) {
        $this->db =& $db;
    }

    function cache_execute( $array = NULL , $cache = FALSE , $cacheTime = 1800 ) {
        if( is_a( $cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
            $this->cache = $cache;
            $this->queryCacheTime = $cacheTime;
            $this->cacheQuery = $this->queryString;
            if( $array !== NULL ) {
                foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    $this->cacheQuery = str_replace(':' . $key , "'" . addslashes( $value ) . "'", $this->cacheQuery );
                }
            }
            $this->debugData( 'Trying to get data from cache for query: ' . $this->cacheQuery . ' (' . md5( $this->cacheQuery ) . ')' );
            $this->cacheQuery = md5( $this->cacheQuery );
            try {
                $this->cacheReturn = $this->cache->get( $this->cacheQuery );
                $this->debugData( 'Reporting return: ' . var_export( $this->cacheReturn , TRUE ) );
            }
            catch ( \Exception $e ) {
                $this->cacheReturn = FALSE;
                $this->debugData( $e->getMessage() );
            }
            if( is_null( $this->cacheReturn ) || $this->cacheReturn == FALSE || is_null( $this->cacheQuery ) || !is_a( $this->cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
                if ($array === null) {
                    parent::execute();
                } else {
                    parent::execute($array);
                }
            }   
        } else {
            if ($array === null) {
                parent::execute();
            } else {
                parent::execute($array);
            }
        }
    }

    function fetch( $fetchStyle = \PDO::FETCH_BOTH, $cursor_orientation = \PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT , $cursor_offset = 0 ) {
        if( is_null( $this->cacheReturn ) || $this->cacheReturn == FALSE || is_null( $this->cacheQuery ) || !is_a( $this->cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
            $fullResults = parent::fetchAll();
            if( is_a( $this->cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
                $this->debugData( 'Inserting data into cache:' . print_r( $fullResults , TRUE ) );
                $this->cache->set($this->cacheQuery , $fullResults , MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED , $cacheTime );
            }
            return parent::fetch( $fetchStyle , $cursor_orientation = \PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT , $cursor_offset = 0 );
        }
        else {
            $this->debugData( 'Returning Cached Results' );
            switch ($fetchStyle) {
                case \PDO::FETCH_BOTH:
                    return $this->cacheReturn[$cursor_offset];
                    break;

                case \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:
                    $data = $this->cacheReturn[$cursor_offset];
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        if( is_numeric( $key ) ) {
                            unset( $data[$key] );
                        }
                    }
                    return $data;
                    break;

                case \PDO::FETCH_LAZY:
                    $data = $this->cacheReturn[$cursor_offset];
                    $return = new \stdClass();
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        if( !is_numeric( $key ) ) {
                            $return->$key = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return $return;
                    break;

                case \PDO::FETCH_OBJ:
                    $data = $this->cacheReturn[$cursor_offset];
                    $return = new \stdClass();
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        if( !is_numeric( $key ) ) {
                            $return->$key = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return $return;
                    break;

                default:
                    return $this->cacheReturn[$cursor_offset];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    function fetchAll() {
        if( is_null( $this->cacheReturn ) || $this->cacheReturn == FALSE || is_null( $this->cacheQuery ) || !is_a( $this->cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
            $fullResults = parent::fetchAll();
            if( is_a( $this->cache , 'Memcache' ) ) {
                $this->debugData( 'Inserting data into cache: ' . print_r( $fullResults , TRUE ) );
                $this->cache->set($this->cacheQuery , $fullResults , MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED , $this->queryCacheTime );
            }
            return $fullResults;
        } else {
            $this->debugData( 'Returning Cached Results' );
            return $this->cacheReturn;
        }
    }

    private function debugData( $data ) {
        if( isset( $_GET['debug'] ) && $_GET['debug'] = DEBUGVAL ) {
            print('<pre>');
            print_r( $data );
            print('</pre>');
        }
    }
}
```

While the solution still does not handle all of the flags that can be set for either `PDOStatement::fetch()` or `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`, it can be further extended to do so.

I've run some tests so far with very good results.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you do not mix your cache access logic with your DB access logic. In other words, I would not try to extend DB-specific classes in order to write to a cache.  After all why try to introduce concepts such as statements, result sets, etc. to a simple caching layer when you don't need to.

I would instead look to a higher level abstraction, maybe a class to which you would pass a valid DB connection and a valid connection to your cache layer (Memcache in your case), and have the class orchestrate the logic for reading/writing to both the cache and DB.

As a high level example (obviously this omits error/exception handling and such):

```
class WriteTroughCache {
    protected $pdo;
    protected $cache;
    protected $cache_ttl = 1000;
    // not shown variouos other options that might be needed for cache or DB

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, Memcache $cache, $options = array()) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        if (!empty($options)) {
            // not shown load options from array into option properties including cache_ttl
        }    
    }

    public get($key) {
        $result = $this-cache->get($key);
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
        // not in cache, get from DB
        $value = $this->db_get($key);
        if (false === $value) {
            // key did not exist in DB
            return false;
        } else {
            // key found in DB
            $this->cache->set($key, $value, 0, $this->cache_ttl);
            return $value;
        }
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        // see if key exists
        // if so, update cache first
        $value = $this->get($key);
        if($value) {
            $this->cache->set($key, $value, 0 , $this->cache_ttl);
        }           
        return $this->db_set($key, $value);
    }

    public function db_get($key) {
        // not shown perform DB query using PDO object
        // return value at key if found or false if not found
    }

    public function db_set($key, $value) {
        // not shown perform DB query using PDO object
        // return true or false based on success of insert
    }
}
```